# css grid uneven height without jQuery Masonry plugin

Tags: css, grid, css-float, grid-layout

Is it possible to have uneven height grid in CSS?
I have taken this illustration from a different question, but the answer to that question was "Use Masonry".

[image: img]

So I want to achieve the result in Figure 1 **But only with 2 columns**.

The reason I don't want to use Masonry is because I want to give those divs themselves slideUp and slideDown animations, and that conflicts with Masonry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the two columns in a `div` then either column would push the div and content below it down. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/anY8P/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col1">
        First col
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        Second col
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, that was actually a brilliant idea. I divided my array into two halves, and put each element in a `col` div, and those two `divs` have both half the width of the container. This gives the illusion of the grids floating,